# Variable References in Javascript. Referencing globals by and acting on them through a function

Tags: javascript, scope

I was reading a article on Javascript Performance that was explaining why local variables are far easier to resolve than global ones. The author said they were creating references in the article and then attached this example (the function snippet).

This example has got me confused, i did not know really know how this function was creating a reference. In my mind I think it should be creating an entirely new object.

In my mind I have become so accustomed to seeing the globals being manipulated from within functions that I am unable to resolve how the global is being manipulated by reference in this example, can anyone give me the details.

```
  function initUI() {
      var doc = document,
          bd = doc.body,
          links = doc.getElementsByTagName("a"),
          i = 0,
          len = links.length;
      while (i < len) {
          update(links[i++]);
      }
      doc.getElementById("go-btn").onclick = function () {
          start();
      };
      bd.className = "active";
  }
```

Comment: Assignment does not copy an object. It just copies the reference to the very same object.

Comment: *" I think it should be creating an entirely new object rather than creating an entirely new object"* o_O

Comment: If this is about performance, then `links = doc.getElementsByTagName("a")` makes no sense when `document.links` exists by default and does not require a call. Similarly, why encourage the use of `...onclick = function(){start()}` and not `...onclick = start`. It just adds an extra function call for no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `document` is a global variable. In theory it's more expensive to resolve a global variable than resolve a variable that lives in the local scope of a function (@RobG pointed out that may not be true in some browsers). Therefore, if you find yourself having to reference a global variable many times, you may consider creating a local reference to that global variable.

E.g. `var doc = document;`

However, that kind of micro-optimizations are rarely necessary and can probably be considered as premature optimizations. It's far more useful to learn how to optimize DOM-related operations.

Comment: "It's more expensive to resolve a global variable than resolve a variable that lives in the local scope of a function" in theory, yes. But compilers are smart and in some browsers at least it has been shown that globals are faster than locals, so not a given. :-)

Comment: @RobG Interesting. Do you have any source? Faster looks suspicious; I would have expected at most no penalty.

Comment: I think it was an early version of IE (maybe 6?). There is an interesting benchmark on [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/global/30), I'm not sure of the validity but in Safari globals aren't that much slower than local. The other 3 tests seem bogus to me in all browsers—"mixed" is virtually identical to "cached globals" and the "scope chain cost" should be similar to global but varies wildly.